# Subclassing NSOperation to be concurrent and cancellable

Tags: iphone, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, performselector

I am unable to find good documentation about how to subclass `NSOperation` to be concurrent and also to support cancellation. I read the Apple docs, but I am unable to find an "official" example.

Here is my source code :

```
@synthesize isExecuting = _isExecuting;
@synthesize isFinished = _isFinished;
@synthesize isCancelled = _isCancelled;

- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)start
{
/* WHY SHOULD I PUT THIS ?
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }
*/

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];


    if (_isCancelled == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"** OPERATION CANCELED **");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Operation started.");
        sleep(1);
        [self finish];
    }
}

- (void)finish
{
    NSLog(@"operationfinished.");

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    _isExecuting = NO;
    _isFinished = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    if (_isCancelled == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"** OPERATION CANCELED **");
    }
}
```

In the example I found, I don't understand why performSelectorOnMainThread: is used. It would prevent my operation from running concurrently.

Also, when I comment out that line, I get my operations running concurrently. However, the `isCancelled` flag is not modified, even though I have called `cancelAllOperations`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Okay, so as I understand it, you have two questions:

1. Do you need the `performSelectorOnMainThread:` segment that appears in comments in your code? What does that code do?
2. Why is the `_isCancelled` flag is not modified when you call `cancelAllOperations` on the `NSOperationQueue` that contains this operation?

Let's deal with these in order. I'm going to assume that your subclass of `NSOperation` is called `MyOperation`, just for ease of explanation. I'll explain what you're misunderstanding and then give a corrected example.

### 1. Running NSOperations concurrently

Most of the time, you'll use `NSOperation`s with an `NSOperationQueue`, and from your code, it sounds like that's what you're doing. In that case, your `MyOperation` will always be run on a background thread, regardless of what the `-(BOOL)isConcurrent` method returns, since `NSOperationQueue`s are explicitly designed to run operations in the background.

As such, you generally do not need to override the `-[NSOperation start]` method, since by default it simply invokes the `-main` method. That is the method you should be overriding. The default `-start` method already handles setting `isExecuting` and `isFinished` for you at the appropriate times.

So if you want an `NSOperation` to run in the background, simply override the `-main` method and put it on an `NSOperationQueue`.

The `performSelectorOnMainThread:` in your code would cause every instance of `MyOperation` to always perform its task on the main thread. Since only one piece of code can be running on a thread at a time, this means that no other `MyOperation`s could be running. The whole purpose of `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` is to do something in the background.

The only time you want to force things onto the main thread is when you're updating the user interface. If you need to update the UI when your `MyOperation` finishes, *that* is when you should use `performSelectorOnMainThread:`. I'll show how to do that in my example below.

### 2. Cancelling an NSOperation

`-[NSOperationQueue cancelAllOperations]` calls the `-[NSOperation cancel]` method, which causes subsequent calls to `-[NSOperation isCancelled]` to return `YES`. **However**, you have done two things to make this ineffective.

1. You are using `@synthesize isCancelled` to override NSOperation's `-isCancelled` method. There is no reason to do this. `NSOperation` already implements `-isCancelled` in a perfectly acceptable manner.
2. You are checking your own `_isCancelled` instance variable to determine whether the operation has been cancelled. `NSOperation` guarantees that `[self isCancelled]` will return `YES` if the operation has been cancelled. It does **not** guarantee that your custom setter method will be called, nor that your own instance variable is up to date. You should be checking `[self isCancelled]`

### What you should be doing

The header:

```
// MyOperation.h
@interface MyOperation : NSOperation {
}
@end
```

And the implementation:

```
// MyOperation.m
@implementation MyOperation

- (void)main {
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        NSLog(@"** operation cancelled **");
    }

    // Do some work here
    NSLog(@"Working... working....")

    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        NSLog(@"** operation cancelled **");
    }
    // Do any clean-up work here...

    // If you need to update some UI when the operation is complete, do this:
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateButton) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    NSLog(@"Operation finished");
}

- (void)updateButton {
    // Update the button here
}
@end
```

Note that you do not need to do anything with `isExecuting`, `isCancelled`, or `isFinished`. Those are all handled automatically for you. Simply override the `-main` method. It's that easy.

(A note: technically, this is not a "concurrent" `NSOperation`, in the sense that `-[MyOperation isConcurrent]` would return `NO` as implemented above. However, it *will* be run on a background thread. The `isConcurrent` method really should be named `-willCreateOwnThread`, as that is a more accurate description of the method's intention.)

Comment: +1 note, however, that subclassing `NSOperation` is generally unneeded, since you can get quite a bit of functionality out of the `NSInvocationOperation` subclass.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great explanation.
@Dave DeLong, subclassing an NSOperation is needed if you want to cancel it, since NSInvocationOperation does not provide a cancel method,isnt'it?

Comment: I agree with all of this except for the part where you trigger UI changes from an operation. Operations shouldn't be directly linked to UI, this is more model work, not view work.

Comment: BJ Homer, just one question. Let's say my operation, in one part of the logic, downloads a large file using ASIHTTPRequest using an asyn request. How should I cancel that request?
If I overwrite cancel, I guess is not a good idea to cancel an ongoing request from another thread, because cancel is called from the user interface, that is, main thread.
What do you think about this code?  
`-(void) cancel {`  
`if (request) {`  
`[request clearDelegateAndCancel];` 
`[request release];`  
`request=nil;`  
`[super cancel];`  
`}`

Comment: @Ricardo You should not override `-cancel`, as that will happen on the calling thread. Instead, you should periodically check `[self isCancelled]` within your operation's logic, and bail out appropriately if it is set.

Comment: Thanks BJ Homer. After reading this technical note:  
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2109/_index.html  
I see you are right.  
However, how should I cancel a long request?  
Thanks.

Comment: There is a nice implementation of NSOperation + NSURLConnection here: https://gist.github.com/578636 It quite resembles some of the code shown in WWDC 2012 Session 225 : "Up and Running : Making a Great Impression with Every Launch".

Answer (score 5):

The excellent answer of @BJHomer deserves an update.

Concurrent operations should override the `start` method instead of `main`.

As stated in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/):

If you are creating a concurrent operation, you need to override the following methods and properties at a minimum:

- `start`
- `asynchronous`
- `executing`
- `finished`

A proper implementation also *requires* to override `cancel` as well. Making a subclass *thread-safe* and getting the required semantics right is also quite tricky.

Thus, I've put a complete and working subclass as a [proposal implemented in Swift](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107659/canonical-implementation-for-a-concurrent-subclass-of-nsoperation-in-swift-2) in Code Review. Comments and suggestion are welcome.

This class can be easily used as a base class for your custom operation class.

Comment: I saw many examples, but only yours payed attention to thread safe for getting value of isExecuting and isFinished.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I've been investigating this lately and encountered the same examples and had the same doubts.

If all your work can be run synchronously inside the main method, you don't need a concurrent operation , neither overriding start, just do your work and return from main when done.

However, if your workload is asynchronous by nature - i.e loading a NSURLConnection, you must subclass start. When your start method returns, the operation isn't finished yet. It will only be considered finished by the NSOperationQueue when you manually send KVO notifications to the isFinished and isExecuting flags (for instance, once the async URL loading finishes or fails).

Lastly, one might want to dispatch start to the main thread when the async workload you want to start require a run-loop listening on the main thread. As the work itself is asynchronous, it won't limit your concurrency, but starting the work in a worker thread might not have a proper runloop ready.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).  It is an HTTP wrapper class built on top of `NSOperation` as a subclass and seems to implement these. Note that as of mid-2011, the developer recommends not using ASI for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding define "**cancelled**" property (or define "**_cancelled**" iVAR) inside NSOperation subclass, normally that is NOT necessary. Simply because when USER triggers the cancellation, custom code should always notify KVO observers that your operation is now **finished** with its work. In other words, **isCancelled => isFinished.**

Particularly, when NSOperation object is dependent on the completion of other operation objects, it monitors the isFinished key path for those objects. Failing to generate a finish notification (**in case of cancellation happens**) can therefore prevent the execution of other operations in your application.

---

BTW, @BJ Homer's answer: "The isConcurrent method really should be **named -willCreateOwnThread" makes A LOT sense**!

Because if you do NOT override start-method,simply manually call NSOperation-Object's default-start-method, calling-thread itself is, by default, synchronous; so, NSOperation-Object is only a non-concurrent operation.

However, if you DO override start-method, inside start-method implementation, custom-code **should spawn a separate thread**…etc,then you successfully break the restriction of "calling-thread default being synchronous", therefore making NSOperation-Object becoming a concurrent-operation, it can run asynchronously afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

This blog post:

http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/09/13/snowy_concurrent_operations/

explains why you might need:

```
if (![NSThread isMainThread])
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    return;
}
```

in your `start` method.