# Using NSThread sleep in an NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, nsrunloop

Working with some code, I'm coming across run loops, which I'm new to, inside `NSOperation`s.

The `NSOperation`s are busy downloading data - and whilst they are busy, there is code to wait for the downloads to complete, in the form of `NSRunLoop`s and thread sleeping.

This code in particular is of interest to me:

```
while (aCertainConditionIsTrue && [self isCancelled]==NO) {
     if(![[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]]){
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
     }
}
```

I've read about the run loops, and `runMode:beforeDate:` will wait for an input source or a timeout. Although I'm not 100% what counts as an input souce.

On the first execution of this it always returns NO and hits the `sleepForTimeInterval:`. Is this bad?

In a particular utility class, it's hitting the `sleepForTimeInterval:` a lot - once for each thread - which significantly hurts the performance.

Any better solutions for this, or advice?

Answer (score 2):

Sleeping locks up the thread. Perhaps you change your code to use  performSelector:withObject:afterDelay. That way your thread can continue to run.

```
    ...
    done = NO;
    [self checkDoneCondition:nil];
    ...

- (void)checkDoneCondition:(id)object {
    if (aCertainConditionIsTrue && [self isCancelled]==NO) {
        if(...) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(checkDoneCondition:) withObject:[con error] afterDelay:1.0];
        } else {
            done = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use a **concurrent** NSOperation. Here is the relevant part in the Apple docs:

> In contrast to a non-concurrent operation, which runs synchronously, a
>   concurrent operation runs asynchronously. In other words, when you
>   call the start method of a concurrent operation, that method could
>   return before the corresponding task is completed. This might happen
>   because the operation object created a new thread to execute the task
>   or because the operation called an asynchronous function. It does not
>   actually matter if the operation is ongoing when control returns to
>   the caller, only that it could be ongoing.
>   (...)
>   In a concurrent operation, your start method is responsible for
>   starting the operation in an asynchronous manner. Whether you spawn a
>   thread or call an asynchronous function, you do it from this method.
>   Upon starting the operation, your start method should also update the
>   execution state of the operation as reported by the isExecuting
>   method. You do this by sending out KVO notifications for the
>   isExecuting key path, which lets interested clients know that the
>   operation is now running. Your isExecuting method must also return the
>   status in a thread-safe manner.

(from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

In other words, you can override the `-start` method in your NSOperation subclass, and have ivar for the `executing` and `finished` property. This method will start the download in a separate thread. When the download starts, you set the `executing` flag and trigger KVO. WHen it is finished in this thread, you do the same with `finished` and `executing`. It seems complicated but it's actually quite simple.

See also this question on Stack Overflow with a great explanation: [Subclassing NSOperation to be concurrent and cancellable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859631/subclassing-nsoperation-to-be-concurrent-and-cancellable)