# NSBlockOperation or NSOperation with ALAsset Block to display photo-library images using ALAsset URL

Tags: iphone, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, alassetslibrary, nsblockoperation

I am asking this question regarding my questions [Display photolibrary images in an effectual way iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545396/display-photolibrary-images-in-an-effectual-way-iphone) and *[Highly efficient UITableView "cellForRowIndexPath" method to bind the PhotoLibrary images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135915/highly-efficiant-uitableview-cellforrowindexpath-method-to-bind-the-photolibra)*.

So I would like to request that answers are not duplicated to this one without reading the below details :)

Let's come to the issue,

I have researched detailed about my above mentioned issue, and I have found the document about **operation queues** from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html).

So I have created one sample application to display seven photo-library images using operation queues through ALAsset blocks.

Here are the sample application details.

**Step 1:**

In the NSOperationalQueueViewController **viewDidLoad** method, I have retrieved all the photo-gallery ALAsset [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in to an array named `urlArray`.

**Step 2:**

After all the URLs are added to the `urlArray`, the  **if(group != nil)** condition will be false in `assetGroupEnumerator`, so I have created a `NSOperationQueue`, and then created seven UIImageView's through a `for` loop and created my `NSOperation` subclass object with the corresponding **image-view** and **URL** for each one and **added** them in to the `NSOperationQueue`.

See my `NSOperation` subclass [here](http://pastebin.com/MeYdde8h).

**See my implementation (VierwController) class** [here](http://pastebin.com/aA3XkE7k).

Let's come to the issue.

It not displaying all the seven images consistently. Some of the images are missing. The missing order is changing multiple times (one time it doesn't display the sixth and seventh, and another time it doesn't display only the second and third). The console log displays **Could not find photo pic number**. However, the URLs are logged properly.

You can see the log details [here](http://pastebin.com/b2wJGM6s).

Are there any mistakes in my classes?

Also, when I go through the above mentioned [operational queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html) documentation, I have read about `NSBlockOperation`. Do I need to implement `NSBlockOperation` instead of `NSOperation` while dealing with ALAsset blocks?

The `NSBlockOperation` description says

> A class you use as-is to execute one or more block objects
>   concurrently. Because it can execute more than one block, a block
>   operation object operates using a group semantic; only when all of the
>   associated blocks have finished executing is the operation itself
>   considered finished.

How can I implement the `NSBlockOperation` with ALAsset block regarding my sample application?

I have gone through Stack Overflow question *[Learning NSBlockOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009027/learning-nsblockoperation)*. However, I didn't get any idea to implement the `NSBlockOperation` with ALAsset block!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a line in your DisplayImages NSOperation subclass where you update the UI (DisplayImages.m line 54):

```
self.imageView.image = topicImage;
```

This operation queue is running on a background thread, and we know that you should only update the state of the UI on the main thread. Since updating the view of an image view is definitely updating the UI, this can be simply fixed by wrapping the call with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   self.imageView.image = topicImage;
});
```

This puts an asynchronous call on the main queue to update the UIImageView with the image. It's asynchronous so your other tasks can be scheduled in the background, and it's safe as it is running on the main queue - which is the main thread.

Comment: great... " i saw he following line earlier " you should only update the state of the UI on the main thread" . Now i well understood its meaning :).. thanks abizern. u rockzzzz...

Answer (score 5):

**This is the tutorial about "How to access all images from iPhonePhoto Library using ALAsset Library and show them on UIScrollView like iPhoneSimulator" .**
First of all add `AssetsLibrary.framework` to your project.

Then in your `viewController.h` file import `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` header file.

This is your `viewController.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary;
    NSMutableArray *groups;
    ALAssetsGroup *assetsGroup;

   // I will show all images on `UIScrollView`
    UIScrollView *myScrollView;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

    NSMutableArray *assetsArray;
    // Will handle thumbnail of images 
    NSMutableArray *imageThumbnailArray;
    // Will handle original images 
    NSMutableArray *imageOriginalArray;

    UIButton *buttonImage;
 }

-(void)displayImages;
-(void)loadScrollView;

@end
```

And this is your `viewController.m` file - 
`viewWillAppear:`

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  assetsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  imageThumbnailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  imageOriginalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 416.0)];
  myScrollView.delegate = self;
  myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 416.0);
  myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
  activityIndicator.center = myScrollView.center;
  [myScrollView addSubview:activityIndicator];
  [self.view addSubview:myScrollView];

  [activityIndicator startAnimating];

}
```

`viewDidAppear:`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 if (!assetsLibrary) {
        assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    }
    if (!groups) {
     groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  } 
 else {
     [groups removeAllObjects];
 }

 ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock listGroupBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        //NSLog(@"group %@",group);
        if (group) {
            [groups addObject:group];
         //NSLog(@"groups %@",groups);
     } else {
         //Call display Images method here.
         [self displayImages];
        }
 };
 ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
     NSString *errorMessage = nil;
        switch ([error code]) {
         case ALAssetsLibraryAccessUserDeniedError:
            case ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError:
             errorMessage = @"The user has declined access to it.";
                break;
            default:
             errorMessage = @"Reason unknown.";
             break;
     }
    };
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:listGroupBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];

}
```

And this is `displayImages:` method body

```
-(void)displayImages
{
// NSLog(@"groups %d",[groups count]);
  for (int i = 0 ; i< [groups count]; i++) {
     assetsGroup = [groups objectAtIndex:i];
        if (!assetsArray) {
         assetsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        else {
         [assetsArray removeAllObjects];
     }

     ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

            if (result) {
                [assetsArray addObject:result];
            }
     };
        ALAssetsFilter *onlyPhotosFilter = [ALAssetsFilter allPhotos];
        [assetsGroup setAssetsFilter:onlyPhotosFilter];
        [assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetsEnumerationBlock];

    }

    //Seprate the thumbnail and original images
    for(int i=0;i<[assetsArray count]; i++)
    {
        ALAsset *asset = [assetsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = [asset thumbnail];
        UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef];
        [imageThumbnailArray addObject:thumbnail];

        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef originalImage = [representation fullResolutionImage];
        UIImage *original = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage];
        [imageOriginalArray addObject:original];
    }

    [self loadScrollView];
}
```

Now you have two `array` one is `imageThumbnailArray` and another is `imageOriginalArray`.
Use `imageThumbnailArray` for showing on `UIScrollView` for which your scrolling will not be slow.... And use `imageOriginalArray` for an enlarged preview of image.

'loadScrollView:' method, This is how to images on `UIScrollView` like **iPhoneSimulator**

```
#pragma mark - LoadImages on UIScrollView
-(void)loadScrollView
{
    float horizontal = 8.0;
    float vertical = 8.0;

    for(int i=0; i<[imageThumbnailArray count]; i++)
    {
        if((i%4) == 0 && i!=0)
        {
            horizontal = 8.0;
            vertical = vertical + 70.0 + 8.0;
        }

        buttonImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [buttonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(horizontal, vertical, 70.0, 70.0)];
        [buttonImage setTag:i];
    [   buttonImage setImage:[imageThumbnailArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonImage addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonImagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [myScrollView addSubview:buttonImage];
        horizontal = horizontal + 70.0 + 8.0;

    }

    [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, vertical + 78.0)];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And here you can find which image `button` has been clicked -

```
#pragma mark - Button Pressed method
-(void)buttonImagePressed:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"you have pressed : %d button",[sender tag]);   
}
```

Hope this tutorial will help you and many users who search for the same.. Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. My requirement to display the photo library images using their ALAsset url's. Lets consider i have all the photo-library image url's in my database before launching the app. for the above (ur answer) purpose, i can display the photo-library images through "UIImagePickerController" without using the ALSAsset. right? so please post the answer for "displaying the photo library images using their ALAsset url's. i think you can answer.

Comment: where is being UIImagePickerController used ????,....nslog the `assetsArray` .. you will see it contains url of all images....

Comment: Sorry if i am wrong :). let clarify one thing.i think assetsArray array contains ALAsset objects. not a NSUrl or Asset url. right?