# ALAssetsLibrary is too slow - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary

What is a fast way to load 10-20 fullscreen images from a camera roll, saved photos?

I'm using this code, but to load 10 photos I need to wait about 5-10 seconds. I'm using iPhone 4S.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(_savedPhotos.count>=11) *stop = YES;
    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *needToStop) {
        NSLog(@"%d",index);
        if(_savedPhotos.count<11)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:result.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage];
            [_savedPhotos addObject:image];
        }
        else
        {
            *needToStop = YES;
        }
    }];
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **ALAssetsLibrary** library will run on a *separate* thread. So it may take time to communicate with the [UI](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/UI#Initialism) related and other stuff.

So use **`-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`** inside the ALAssetsLibrary block.

***Change your code as below***

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *needToStop) {
            NSLog(@"%d",index);
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:result.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(usePhotolibraryimage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
        }];
    }

    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
    }];

- (void)usePhotolibraryimage:(UiImage *)myImage{

    //Do your all UI related and all stuff here
}
```

**Note**:Look on [this issue too](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/10/15/solve-xcode-error-invalid-attempt-to-access-alassetprivate-past-the-lifetime-of-its-owning-alassetslibrary/).

Comment: I've implemented your code and changed fullscreen image to thumbnail, and save ALAsset *result to NSMutableArray, and access it when I need.  It is much faster and takes less memory.

Comment: you don't want to convert the  image to thumbnail manually.. ALAssetsLibrary will directly provide thumbnails

Comment: LAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
  {

   CGImageRef iref = [myasset thumbnail];


       if (iref) {

             importMediaSaveImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];

             }

Comment: also please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580918/nsblockoperation-or-nsoperation-with-alasset-block-to-display-photo-library-imag

Comment: One thing to be aware of: if your user has not given Photos permissions yet, they will be asked the first time via a UIAlertView. This must be on the main thread. So take that into consideration.