# How to arrange dynamically created UILabels inside UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

I am dynamically creating `UILabels` from an array using a `for` loop.

Each `UILabel` has a different length. When I created the `UILabels`, they are overlapping one another.

I want to arrange those `UILabels` properly inside the `UIView` without any overlapping. Any help?

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580918/nsblockoperation-or-nsoperation-with-alasset-block-to-display-photo-library-imag/11607592#11607592) and look at the `-(void)loadScrollView` method. You need to make x,y origin dynamic. It will make imageView grid same like photo gallery.

Comment: @DanielMartín, No because it's giving me problems with other functions inside the view.

Comment: @IOS7beta2 is my answer useful for you?

Comment: @IOS7beta2 please check the source it is 100% worked. if you have questions, just ask me.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander I did check it,did you check it with IOS 7 and 4.0 Retina display..? didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find how it works here: [arrange labels sources link](https://github.com/matrosovDev/ArrangeLabels)

1. Download sources using appropriate button on site
2. Open ArrangeLabels project
3. Open `ViewController.m` file
4. Check -`createElements` `-fitElements` methods from the sources.

If you want you can view sources here immediately in your browser: [link to code](https://github.com/matrosovDev/ArrangeLabels/blob/master/ArrangeLabels/ViewController.m)

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfectly in IOS 7. But I replace 


  CGSize expectedLabelSize = [str sizeWithFont:label.font
                                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 10)
                                       lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
        
        CGRect rect = [label frame];
        rect.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
        rect.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height; with sizeToFit because of deprecating.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `sizeToFit` and `numberOfLines=0`

```
 int y=0;
    for (int k=0; k<[array count]; k++)
    {
        UILabel *lb=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5 , y, 100,60)];

        lb.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
        lb.text=[array objejectAtIndex:k];
        lb.numberOfLines=0;
        [lb sizeToFit];
        [self.view addSubview:lb];
        y+=lb.frame.size.height;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Try to implement this logic:


    -(void)adjustLabel1Text1:(NSString *)text1 
    {
        UILabel *lbl_first = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];



        text1 = [text1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


        float hedingLblHeight = [self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:text1 : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] :118 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        lbl_first.text=text1;


        [lbl_first setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_first.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y, 118, hedingLblHeight)];
        lbl_first.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        lbl_first.numberOfLines = 0;
        [lbl_first sizeToFit];




    //////////Adjust the lable or any UIControl below this label accordingly.

        float endResultHeight=[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:text2 : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15] :299 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        if(hedingLblHeight>secondImgTitleHeight)
        {
        [lbl_endResult setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_endResult.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y+lbl_first.frame.size.height+5, 299, endResultHeight)];
        }
        else
        {
            [lbl_endResult setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_endResult.frame.origin.x, lbl_first.frame.origin.y+lbl_first.frame.size.height+5, 299, endResultHeight)];

        }

        lbl_endResult.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        lbl_endResult.numberOfLines = 0;
        [lbl_endResult sizeToFit];



    }

    -(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*)text : (UIFont*) withFont:(float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
    {

        CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

        return suggestedSize.height;
    }

It has helped me a lot.Hope it works for you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change y coordinate of your label like this

```
UILabel *hiLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,50,20)];
hiLbl.text = @"Hi";
[self.view addSubview:hiLbl];

UILabel *hellolbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,30,50,20)];
hellolbl.text = @"Hi";
[self.view addSubview:hellolbl];
```

or

```
UILabel *lbl;

for(int i = 1 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
     lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,i*10+10,50,20)];
     [self.view addSubview:lbl];
     lbl.text = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any screenshot it is difficult to guess what type of **overlapping** you are referring to. And length of `UILabel` does not help, either specify- width or height.

But if you are talking about width of `UILabel`, then this piece of code may help you.

Lets you have three labels of different widths, which are in an array of widths array:{ 10, 20, 30}.

```
float width = [array objectAtIndex:0];
float x = 0.of;
float padding = 10.0f;
for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
 UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
 [self.view addSubview: label];
 x = x + width + paddng;
 width =  [array objectAtIndex:i + 1];
}
```