# NSOperation accessing isCancelled in main

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsoperation

### Current status

I have created a custom `NSOperation` object and I want to update some data when it is cancelled.

I've followed what said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300849/778374) and I **didn't** override the `cancel` method.

Here is my header:

```
// MyOperation.h
@interface MyOperation : NSOperation {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) OtherDataClass *dataClass;
@end
```

And the implementation

```
// MyOperation.m
@implementation MyOperation

@synthesize dataClass;

- (void)main {
    if ([self isCancelled]) {

        [self.dataClass setStatusCanceled];

        NSLog(@"Operation cancelled");
    }

    // Do some work here
    NSLog(@"Working... working....")

    [self.dataClass setStatusFinished];

    NSLog(@"Operation finished");
}

@end
```

### The question

I have several operations in a queue. I was expecting that, when I call `cancelAllOperations` in the queue, I'll get the *"Operation cancelled"* text in the log and the status updated in my other class but it is not working. The `main` method is not being called for the operations in the queue.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

### Notes

I've tried to overwrite the `cancel` method with this:

```
- (void)cancel {
    [super cancel];
    [self.dataClass setStatusCanceled];
    NSLog(@"Operation cancelled");
}
```

It is working but I've read that this method should not be overridden.

Comment: I don't see why `main` would be called again? i.e you start your NSOperation `main` is called and does its thing. Calling `cancelAllOperations` would not call `main` again as this would just start "the work" again? I don't see anything in the docs stating you should not override `cancel`. Can you give a reference.

Comment: I don't want to call `main` more than once. I have, for example, 5 operations in a queue. If I call `cancelAllOperations` when computing the third, I expect obtaining the _"Operation finished"_ for the first two and the current one (when finished) and then the _"Operation cancelled"_ text for the last two ones. But I'm not getting the last two log lines, because `main` doesn't seem to be called for the last two ones, once the queue has been canceled.

Regarding overriding `cancel` method, I saw it in several StackOverflow answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `cancelAllOperations`, the operations which are already started will have `isCancelled` set to `YES`. operations which aren't already started won't start.